# We may never know why we were born, and why certain people come into our life - lives

Tags: grammar

Is lives correct?  I want to use life.

We may never know why we were born, and why certain people come into our life - lives.

Answer (score 1):

"We" and "our" are plural, so "lives" should be plural, too. If you want to use life, then the entire sentence needs to be recast from first person plural (we, our) to first person singular (I, my).

Comment: There are other readings of this in which the singular is just fine there.  It is not so clear-cut as you would have it appear.